# Automatic SASS to CSS in RoR 3 without sass --watch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass

I've read all topics re. SASS + RoR, but there are no answers for my small question. I'm running Rails 3 and using alternate syntax, without SCSS. Haml gem included in the project. What else should I configure to have autogenerated css files without "sass --watch"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to put `gem "haml"` in your Gemfile, then put your Sass files in `public/stylesheets/sass`.

Comment: Wow.  That was awesome!  Worked like a charm, go HAML and Rails 3.

Comment: Yep, that's was a specific issue with this particular project. Works!